# Настройка, против взлома

Tags: yii, yii2

Как правильно настроить модель, нужно ли использовать **safe**? Судя из той тонны материала который я прочел, то в **Yii2** его указывать не нужно если атрибут засветился в каком-нибудь правиле валидации. Это правда?

> В Yii 2.x безопасными по умолчанию являются все атрибуты, когда либо
>   упомянутые в правилах модели (метод rules()). А валидатор safe нужен
>   лишь для того, чтобы атрибут «засветился» в правилах модели и тем
>   самым стал безопасным. Т.е safe-валидатор в Yii 2.x не влияет на
>   безопасность атрибута уже упомянутого в правилах!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Валидатор safe ни от чего не защищает. Фишка в том, что если у нужного свойства модели нет никаких валидаторов - на него не будет распрастраняться mass assignment, т.е. тот момент, когда вы, например, в контроллере, принимающем форму ввода, пишете что-то вроде `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` и все соотв. поля заполняются автоматом.

Защита от "взлома" как раз в этом моменте: если у модели, к примеру, не валидируется свойство id, то и указав руками в форме поле ввода id - его не перепишешь масс-присваиванием, а только явно написав в коде `$model->id = ...`

Соотв-но, чтобы разрешить масс-присваивание свойству, у которого ничего не валидируется - введен этот safe валидатор, он по сути просто декларирует отсутствие проверок у свойства с одновременной возможностью его записи при масс-присваиваниях на свой страх и риск.